# How do I test if some digits of a users input (phone number) correspond to some specific ones I set?

Tags: python-3.x

```
userPhoneNumberInput = input("Enter your phone number: ")

if len(userPhoneNumberInput) != 11:
    print("Please enter a correct phone number: ")

elif len(userPhoneNumberInput) == 11:

    if userPhoneNumberInput.isdigit():
    print("Please check to see that your number contains only digits")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:3] == 0803,0703,0903:
    print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using an Mtn number")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:3] == 0805,0705,0905:
    print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using a Glo number")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:3] == 0809,0909,0817:
    print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using an Etisilat number")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:3] == 0802,0702,0701:
    print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using an Airtel number")

else:
    print ("Oga your number is Alien!")
```

I've searched the net for ways to confirm that some specific numbers correspond to the ones I've set for a test. I'm not sure of the particular title for this question.

What I'm trying to do in the code as pictured, is confirm if the last 3 users input (phone number) after the first digit, corresponds to the ones I've listed.

Ps: I'm a python newbie.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. Please [edit] your post to provide the code, properly formatted, clearly explain the problem you're having with that code, and ask a specific question, and we can try to help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried searching your error message? If you have, you probably would find that you need "or"s in your elif statements. For future reference, please try to do some more research as this is a relatively simple question. And for asking questions on SO, please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it usually helps if you post your code in your post using Ctrl+k. We don't like reading from images :P

Comment: It would be better if you would write your code in the question, than post it with images.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  #I'm not even eligible to post images, I just found out.

Answer (score 0):

```
userPhoneNumberInput = input("Enter your phone number: ")

if len(userPhoneNumberInput) != 11:
    print("Please enter a correct phone number: ")
else:
    if not userPhoneNumberInput.isdigit():   #Use if not
        print("Please check to see that your number contains only digits")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:4] in ['0803','0703','0903']:
        print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using an Mtn number")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:4] in ['0805','0705','0905']:
        print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using a Glo number")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:4] in ['0809','0909','0817']:
        print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using an Etisilat number")

    elif userPhoneNumberInput[:4] in ['0802','0702','0701']:
        print ("Welcome" + userPhoneNumberInput + "you're using an Airtel number")
```

- Use `in` to check if value in list